# Htaccess http to https with php exception

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, https

I recently changed my website to https and I used an .htaccess re-write to send everything via https using this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

However one page (contact-us.php) is throwing up https errors on a couple of browsers (IE and Chrome) which I looked into fixing but they're tough. The easiest work around for me would be make the offending page (contact-us.php) an exception to the global http to https rule. But how?!

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about htaccess rule and as such better fits to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact-us\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^contact-us\.php http://%{HTTP_HOST}/contact-us.php [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Croises. I did try this method but it doesn't seem to be working. If I type http as the url it goes to the unsecure page but if I navigate to contact-us.php using the relative site links it directs to the https version of the page. I've tried reloading and clearing my browser cache. :/

Comment: You don't ask for redirect the page to http... i add that now in my code

Comment: Update: I have "solved" the https issue by changing one of the site's contact-us.php links to be absolute so it now directs to http://..contact-us.php instead of contact-us.php. The http is sticking but the re-write of https to http for that page is not. Puzzling.

Comment: You can change `R=302` to `R=301`

Comment: Ah Croises I didn't realise I would have to have a redirect for the page, I thought just the exception rule would suffice. Those extra two lines work beautifully. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm going to go with the 301, it's not going to be temporary, there is no need for that page to be secure anyway. :)

Comment: If you can correct the page, you should do it, because for the user switch from one to the other is not a good idea, but not a real problem ;-)

Comment: Well the problem is with Recaptcha on that page which was working fine but when we moved to SSL Chrome refuses to load the Recaptcha box citing security errors. Recaptcha was installed a few years ago but has now has been acquired by Google who have changed the validation server urls and are apparently deliberately serving an invalid certificate to people using the old (now redirecting to Google) url. There are manual instructions to edit the php to the new urls over on the Google Recaptcha developer forum which I followed but all it did was break the Recaptcha on all browsers. :/ Cont...

Comment: ...I then decided that re-installing Recaptcha was the way forward using Google's code with the correct urls but sadly our php page is peppered with validation rules (enter email address, enter name etc.) and I found it impossible to see which was our php and which was the Recaptcha php without breaking the whole thing. Hence I figured the easiest solution would be to use that page unsecurely.